# String split with period (.) shows different Behaviour

Tags: java, string

I was working on `String` and tried with `split()` for `.` like:-

```
String s = "Hi.Hello";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split(".")));
```

The above code outputs `[]` empty array. But if I escape `.` like :-

```
String s = "Hi.Hello";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("\\.")));
```

Its giving correct output as `[Hi, Hello]`.

**So I Want To Know**:-

Why do i need to escape `.` but `.` it is normally not considered a escape character in `String` as we can use `.` directly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `String.split( String )` method takes a regular expression as argument. In a regular expression "." means "any character", so you have to escape it (by adding "\\"), if you actually want to split by "." and not by "any character".

See the api documentation of [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for a starter on the regular expressions.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot split it with just `.` because split()

`Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.`

In regex . means 'match any character', so you have to escape it with \\ instead of \ because you also have to escape the \ character!

Answer (score 1):

*Small addition to previous answers (which are correct).*

It's often better to use `StringUtils.split` from Apache Commons Lang ([javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#split(java.lang.String,%20char))). It takes plain string (instead of regex) as an argument. Also, its behaviour more intuitive:

```
StringUtils.split("a..b.c", ".") = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

vs

```
"a..b.c".split("\\.") = ["a", "", "b", "c"]
```